# Popup/panel does not appear at the right position through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have created a page where a list of members is shown. I created a Javascript function which shows the details of a user in a panel with id `divpreview` with `position:absolute` and `z-index:100` the popup/panel does but I am not able to show it right above the the member.

```
<div runat="server" id="divpreview" class="preview">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function showdiv(id, m, pos) {

            var arr = new Array(7);
            arr = id.split("###");
            var divhtml = "";
            divhtml += "<table border='1'  style='background-color:#1C5E55;color:white;absolute' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>Sponsor Id</td><td>" + arr[0] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Total Left Point</td><td>" + arr[1] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Total Right Point</td><td>" + arr[2] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Total Left Investment</td><td>" + arr[3] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Total Right Investment</td><td>" + arr[4] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Self Point </td><td>" + arr[5] + "</td></tr>";
            divhtml += "<tr><td>Expiry Date</td><td>" + arr[6] + "</td></tr>";

            divhtml += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").innerHTML = divhtml;
            var left = m.clientX + 10;
            if (pos == 1) {
                left = m.clientX - 230;
            }
            else {
                left = m.clientX + 10;
            }
            debugger;

            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.left = left.toString() + 'px';
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.display = "block";
            var top = 0;
            top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + m.clientY - 50;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.top = top.toString() + 'px';
        }
        function hidediv() {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.display = "none";
        }
        function movediv(m, pos) {
            var left = m.clientX + 05;
            if (pos == 1) {
                left = m.clientX - 200;
            }
            else {
                left = m.clientX + 10;
            }

            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.left = left.toString() + 'px';
            var top = 0;
            top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + m.clientY - 50;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpreview").style.top = top.toString() + 'px';
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

I want the panel to appear near the stars. What should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this style on divpreview

```
 <div runat="server" id="divpreview" class="preview" style="position:absolute;z-index:999;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
position: relative;
```

to the parent div. Position absolute element will "stop" when finding the closest positioned relative or positioned absolute element.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work the panel takes up space on page. I want it to appear above the page like a popup.

Comment: do you want it in the middle of the page above everything? could you provide us a fiddle?

Comment: that would keep the position fixed in the middle of the page. I want it to appear right beside the star.

Comment: ah ok, then use only position: fixed and for left, top you can use javascript as you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
```

parent div Position 'absolute'.